# How to simple execute a PHP script with the wordpress library

Tags: php, wordpress, passwords

I just want to test this function:

```
    <?php
        wp_check_password( $password, $hash, $user_id );
?>
```

Where can I execute this script? It just must has the library with wp_check_password() function. That's all. I didn't find a simple way to do this function, so I don't want more advanced things. The values I will fit mannualy.

I appreciate if you can help me!